# How can I get the URL values in PHP from passing value JavaScript to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am passing my URL with values from javascript to PHP like:

```
<script>

    var a= "10-test(8+2) DVI-A Male";
    var b= "8-test(6+2) DVI-A Male";
    var test = a.replace("+", "%2B"); 
    var test1 = b.replace("+", "%2B"); 
    window.open("listing.php?cond=true" + "&a=" + (test.replaceAll("%", " ")) + "&b=" + test1.replaceAll("%", " "));
</script>
```

I have a URL like

```
localhost://listing.php?cond=true&a=10-test%20(8+2)%20DVI-A%20Male&b=test2%20Male
```

I want to get the data of a & b For this I used :

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET["a"];
    $b = $_GET["b"]; ?>
```

But I got the result like

```
$a = 10-test(8 2) DVI-A Male
```

I lost my + symbol in my result. How can I get the result like:

```
10-test(8+2) DVI-A Male
```

Comment: _"I lost my + symbol in my result"_ - The original strings in JS doesn't contain any `+` signs. When you see them in the URL, it's how spaces are encoded. As far as I can tell, what you get in PHP is identical to the string you have in JS. However, you don't need to encode the strings manually at all. Use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) which does the work for you.

Comment: I used encodeURIComponent(a). After I decode the value in PHP. Then again I lost my + symbol

Comment: I added code like:
window.open("listing.php?cond=true" + "&a=" + encodeURIComponent(a) + "&b=" + encodeURIComponent(b));

Answer (score 0):

```
I changed my script like:

<script>
    window.open("listing.php?cond=true" + "&a=" + encodeURIComponent(a) + "&b=" + encodeURIComponent(b));
    </script>
```

And also changed PHP code like:

```
<?PHP 
$_GET['a'] = preg_replace('/%/', ' ', $_GET['a']);
$_GET['b'] = preg_replace('/%/', ' ', $_GET['b']);
?>
```